# Regex- for exact 6 characters, first 3 characters are static and last 3 are number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write `regex` of exact `6` characters long, where first three characters are static (`ABC`) and last `3` characters are numbers (`0-9`). 
Here is my `regex`:

```
^[ABC][0-9]{3}$
```

But I'm not getting results. Any suggestion?

Comment: `[ABC]` means either `A` or `B` or `C`, not `ABC`.

Comment: oh, I want ABC to be in order.

Comment: Then remove the square brackets in your pattern from `[ABC]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
^ABC[0-9]{3}$
```

`[ABC]` - means one character from this set.

Try to play with this regex using [online tool](https://regex101.com/r/aELQw5/1). It will be much easier to understand and develop it.

Comment: @Jay, If my answer worked, consider to accept it. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)